# Can I update a portion of Twitter Bootstrap data-content?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using a popover that I need to dynammicaly change the content of but only a piece of it. More specifically I'm using [bootstrapx-clickover](http://www.leecarmichael.com/bootstrapx-clickover/examples.html) so I can't simply update the data-content because my button to close the popover will be removed.

My current code looks like this:

```
<span class="label label-importan" rel="clickover" data-content="NEW TEXT HERE<button class='btn' data-toggle='button' data-dismiss='clickover'>Close</button>" data-original-title="Title">data</span>
```

If I just call:

```
....
var el = $(this);
el.attr('data-content', "New Data");
....
```

This unfortunately removed the button code.  Is there a way to update only the text for data-content and not the button HTML?

Comment: I ran in to the same problem.  I just had to reload all the html content every time i wanted the popover content to change.

Comment: I tried that but my button trigger to close stops working when I do that...

Comment: you might need to write a custom event handler to close it for the button and put it in an .on() method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the content of the `data-content` attribute remains the same as your example, IE there will always be some text followed by a `<button>` element, you could use some code similar to this -

```
var attributeContent = el.data('content');
var withoutText = txt.replace(/.*<button/,'<button');
el.data('content','SOME NEW TEXT HERE'+withoutText);
```

It's kind of a low-tech solution and it's dependent on the consistency of the `data-content` value, but this might just work in your specific case.

Because you are essentially adding a new element each time (the `<button>` element), you might need to utilize the `delegate()` function on a parent element to allow yourself to attach event handlers to elements that are dynamically generated.